# Using posession 's'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

I have conducted several experiments using several devices. Each device is configured with a list of algorithms. I want to write a title to describe the algorithms used in the devices of the experiments. So I wrote:

> The experiments devices algorithms

Is it grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not grammatically correct.  In its current form, you have three (plural) nouns right next to each other with nothing connecting them, which is pretty much never right.  You need to start with one noun which indicates the actual (single) thing you are talking about, and then you can modify it with additional adjectives or possessive forms, etc. from there.

So in this case, what you're talking about, at its most basic level, is the algorithms, so that should be your base noun.  If you then want to say that the algorithms were used in/by the devices, you can use a possessive form for that.  Note that the possessive form of a plural still requires an apostrophe, it just goes after the "s" instead of before it:

> The devices' algorithms

If you then also want to say that the devices in question were associated with the experiments, you can use another possessive:

> The experiments' devices' algorithms

But chaining possessives like this (while technically correct) often sounds a bit strange, so it's common to use an adjective which implies much the same thing to vary things a bit instead:

> The experimental devices' algorithms

Alternately, you can vary things a bit by indicating the first possession using "of" instead of the apostrophe form:

> The algorithms of the experiments' devices

I would also point out that possessives in general can sound less formal than adjective forms or prepositional phrases, so when people are speaking in a formal tone (such as scientific papers, etc), it is common to minimize their use.  For this reason, you might actually want to say combine the adjective version and the "of" version into something like the following, instead:

> The algorithms of the experimental devices